# Binding TabControl to collection of ViewModels

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

how to bind `TabControl` to `ObservableCollection` of ViewModels? I can't write DataTemplates... more precisely, how to specify what's in the title and what's in the body of each `TabItem`.
I would appreciate mini XAML example, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Header is specified by `ItemTemplate`, body is specified by `ContentTemplate`.

e.g.

```xml
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding DpData}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Occupation}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsActive}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

If you have trouble with bindings and datatemplates read the overviews first:

[Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)
[Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)